# can we delete element in list based on certain condition

Tags: arrays, python-3.x, string

I have a Python list:

```
test_list = ['LeBron James', 'and', 'Nina Mata', 'Dan Brown', 'Derrick Barnes', 'and',
         'Gordon C. James', 'J. Kenji López-Alt', 'and', 'Gianna Ruggiero', ]
```

I want output like this:

```
final_list = ['LeBron James and Nina Mata', 'Dan Brown', 'Derrick Barnes and
         Gordon C. James', 'J. Kenji López-Alt and Gianna Ruggiero']
```

In short, I want one item **before** 'and' one item **after** 'and' to be combined. On the other hand, names coming **without** 'and' should not be combined and left as it is. How can we do this in Python?

Comment: Can you have more than one "and" group? (Like `["A", "and", "B", "and", "C"]`)

Answer (score 0):

Here's a solution perhaps not too elegant but simple and functional: join all words with a glue symbol that does not happen in any of them (e.g., `"~"`), replace the resulting `"~and~"`s with `" and "`s, and split by the glue symbol again:

```
"~".join(test_list).replace("~and~", " and ").split("~")
#['LeBron James and Nina Mata', 'Dan Brown', 
# 'Derrick Barnes and Gordon C. James', 
# 'J. Kenji López-Alt and Gianna Ruggiero']
```

This should work for groups with more than one "and," too.

Comment: Nice hack in practice but not really safe in the general case.

Comment: @wim This is not a general case but a very special case of human names. Please explain.

Comment: To explain: for the code to work with arbitrary strings you would need to guarantee the "glue" was not present in any value, which may not even be possible (e.g., you're processing strings coming in a stream where lookahead is not possible). Since it's easy enough to write a generator-based solution that works without this caveat, why not just do that in the first place. Just my 2c..

Comment: @wim This code is not expected to work with arbitrary strings, but if it is, any non-printable character can be chosen as glue, such as `\x01`.

Comment: @DYZ this code is not working for my scrapy scraper which I have built to extract names of authors from Amazon website. It is breaking each word into letters when I use it in the items.py of Scrapy.

Comment: Please update your example, then. It works on the example that you posted.